# grails 2.5 - how to put a list in config.groovy

Tags: list, grails

Is there any way to put a list in the config.groovy file?  e.g:

```
environments {
    development {
        account {
            defaultList = [1, 3, 5]
        }
```

trying to read this in a service, e.g:

```
def grailsApplication
:
def accountTypesToCreate = grailsApplication.config.account.defaultList
```

results in

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'groovy.util.ConfigObject@66c2331a' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'java.util.List' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.List(groovy.util.ConfigObject)

Also tried getProperty

Comment: That's weird - why would Groovy try to cast to list if nowhere in your code you implicitly or explicitly ask it to do that? The `accountTypesToCreate ` is an object so it should happily take a `ConfigObject ` instance. In other words are you sure it's this the code that throws the exception?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def accountTypesToCreate = grailsApplication.config.account.defaultList as List
```